# Nested IF functions in DAX power bi

Tags: powerbi, crystal-reports, logic, dax

So I have this logic from crystal reports formula builder that I'd like to follow into powerBI's DAX and create a new column with the result:

`if {tableA.Col1} = "PAY" and {tableB.Col#} in ["LEG", "HAND"] and {tableA.Col2} = "Y" then "N" else "Y"`

I cant seem to create any logical statement to refer to another table within DAX (up to my knowledge) or actually nest multiple ifs like above, here is what I have so far..

```
Error = IF(tableA[col1] = "PAY" && IF(tableB[col#] = "LEG"&&"HAND" && IF(tableA[col2] = "Y","N","Y"),"Y"),"Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error Column =
IF (
tableA[col1] = "PAY"
    && RELATED ( tableB[col#] )
        IN { "HANDS", "LEGS" }
        && tableA[col2] = "Y",
"N",
"Y"
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?